# Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 35

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, connection-string

I created a login in SSMS and added a connectionString in Web.config as follows:

```
<add name="KhadamatConnectionString"
         connectionString="data source=.;Database=AcaService; uid=admin pwd='mypass'"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

I get the following error:

**Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
     Exception Details: System.ArgumentException: Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 35.**

this is my code to submit some data:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string connectionString=ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["KhadamatConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    sc.Open();
    if (sc.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
    {
        lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        lblMsg.Text = "خطای ارتباط با پایگاه داده";
        return;
    }
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCmd.Connection = sc;            
    sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCmd.CommandText="INSERT INTO tblComment VALUES(@name,@email,@comment)";
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name",System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar));
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Email",System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar));
    sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Comment",System.Data.SqlDbType.NVarChar));
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@Name"].Value=txtName.Text;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@Email"].Value=txtEmail.Text;
    sqlCmd.Parameters["@Comment"].Value=txtComment.Text;
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);
    lblMsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    lblMsg.Text="اطلاعات ذخیره شد";
    sc.Close();
}
```

Comment: It is just a typo. Missing the semicolon after the uid keyvalue pair

Comment: Sorry, I didn't known I had to use a semicolon after uid keyvalue pair. I did so and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change connection string like this

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="KhadamatConnectionString" 
    value="Server=[copy name from Your ServerName of SSMS];Database=AcaService;uid=admin;pwd=mypass;" />
</appSettings>
```

or

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="KhadamatConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=[copy name from Your ServerName of SSMS];Initial Catalog=AcaService;User ID=admin;Password=mypass;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: the key attribute is not allowed within <connectionStrings> tags

Comment: @misaq Yes Your are right but you can place it inside `appSetting`

Comment: by [copy name from Your login of SSMS], do you mean 'admin' user id I used above?

Comment: @misaq No No. My mistake now updated with 'ServerName'